# PowerShell for-each loop output to file

Tags: powershell

How do I output/append the contents of this `foreach` loop to a text file?

The following below is not working out.

```
$Groups = Get-AdGroup -Properties * -filter * | Where {$_.name -like "www*"}
Foreach($G in $Groups)
{
    write-host " "
    write-host $G.Name
    write-host "----------"
    get-adgroupmember -Identity $G | select-object -Property SamAccountName
    Out-File -filepath C:\test.txt -Append
}
```

Comment: Thomas Stringer's got it.

Comment: Can't you pipe the `Get-ADGroupMember` to `Out-File` within the loop?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$output = 
    Foreach($G in $Groups)
    {
        write-output " " 
        write-output $G.Name
        write-output "----------"
        get-adgroupmember -Identity $G | select-object -Property SamAccountName
    }

$output | Out-File "C:\Your\File.txt"
```

All this does is saves the output of your `foreach` loop into the variable `$output`, and then dumps to data to your file upon completion.

**Note: `Write-Host` will write to the host stream, and not the output stream.  Changing that to `Write-Output` will dump it to the `$output` variable, and subsequently the file upon loop completion.**

The reason your original code isn't working is that you're not actually writing anything to the file.  In other words, you're piping no data to your `Out-File` call.  Either way, my approach prefers a cache-then-dump methodology.

Comment: I tried this but it just stores the header tags of all the jobs. What am i doing wrong?